# How to run a script with a temporary environment variable?

Tags: python, shell

If I have a python scripts with simple lines as the following:

```
import os

name = os.environ.get('BEAR_NAME')
if name != "":
  print("hello, ", name)
```

I'd like to set a temporary environment variable when running this script. Note that if I do

```
export BEAR_NAME="sleepybear"
python hello.py
```

the env var `BEAR_NAME` will still have value `sleepybear` once the python program finishes, which is not desired.
Take docker's example, we can do `docker run -e SOME_VAR=SOME_VAL` to set the environment variable `SOME_VAR`. Is there a similar way when running a python script?

Comment: Why not pass an argument `sys.argv`? . see https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your shell command can be

```sh
BEAR_NAME="sleepybear" python hello.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

##### `hello.py`

```py
import os

BEAR_NAME = 'BEAR_NAME'

def lookup(var):
    name = os.environ.get(var)
    if name is None:
        print(f'Environment variable {var} does not exist')
    else:
        print(f'Hello, {name}!')

lookup(BEAR_NAME)
os.environ[BEAR_NAME] = 'sleepybear'
lookup(BEAR_NAME)
```

##### Sample run

```
> python hello.py
Environment variable BEAR_NAME does not exist
Hello, sleepybear!

> echo %BEAR_NAME%
%BEAR_NAME%

>
```

Tested on Windows